# If $K/F$ is algebraic and $a\in K$ is separable over $F(a^p)$ then $a\in F(a^p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Suppose that $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$. Show that if $K/F$ is algebraic and $a\in K$ is separable over $F(a^p)$ then $a\in F(a^p)$.

I know that the minimal polynomial of $a$ has distinct roots over $F(a^p)$ and the map $\phi:F\rightarrow F$ by $x \mapsto x^p$ is injective. But I am not sure how to approach this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $a$ is the root of $X^p-a^p\in F(a^p)[X]$ this implies that the minimal polynomial of $a$ divides $X^p-a^p=(X-a)^p$.